Xticks labels not showing even with label parameter specified
I am trying to do a very simple timeline :
a bar, the ticks and year labels for each tick.
Here is the code :
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    df3 = df2.head(5)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
    ax.plot(df3.datetimeParse, [0,]* len(df3), "-o", color="black")
    ax.set_xticks(pd.date_range(
        min(df3["datetimeParse"])
        ,max(df3["datetimeParse"])
        , freq="YS")
        ,range(int(min(df3["datetimeParse"]).year)
            ,int(max(df3["datetimeParse"]).year)))

    ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
    plt.show()

I am fairly new to matplotlib and I don't understand what is missing for the year labels to show. (df3["datetimeParse"] dtype is datetime64[ns])
so far this is what I get:


By using ax.set_xticks you set the position of your ticks on the x-axis only but not your labels. To set your labels you should incorporate ax.set_xticklabels into your code thus defining the labels explicitly corresponding to each tick.
For example:
tick_dates = pd.date_range(pd.date_range(
    min(df3["datetimeParse"])
    ,max(df3["datetimeParse"])
    , freq="YS")
    ,range(int(min(df3["datetimeParse"]).year)
        ,int(max(df3["datetimeParse"]).year))) #define your x-ticks

ax.set_xticks(tick_dates) #set your x ticks

ax.set_xticklabels([d.year for d in tick_dates], rotation=45, ha='right') # set x-tick labels to show only the year


Good one!  Thanks!
